# High concentration fuel detergent effects on oil

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-injectors, fuel-additives

I just did an oil change. I was planning on putting some fuel detergent in the tank and run in through before the oil change but forgot. Can I still put it in now without having negative effects on the oil?

I am using the product called ["Guaranteed to Pass"](http://crcg2p.com/) which is just a polyetheramine based detergent. Polyetheramine is generally considered the only real effect fuel system cleaner, and is the main cleaning additive added to basically all fuels at the pump.

My car is GDI. So the detergent would only come in contact with anything in the cylinder and then the exhaust, so I don't see how it could affect the oil, but would love to see if an expert agrees.

Comment: I don't have any empirical evidence, but would think if the cleaner has the same additives as what goes in gasoline, you're not going to harm the oil any. It is a given, *some* of the gasoline (or unspent hydrocarbons) make it into the oil past the rings. The amount which actually makes it past is dependent upon the design of the engine and wear. Even so, the amounts which bypass in a normally operating engine are pretty sparse. Most of it is burned in the combustion cycle. Most of anything left would go out the exhaust port. Leaves only a trace amount which *might* make it to the oil.